# SWIFT pass value to another existed ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have 2 ViewControllers. First one connected with second with 'Show'. When I click 'Add' button on the first - second will appear. Then I need to click on the cell in tableView (in the 2nd VC) and pass it's value to the label of the first VC and segue there.

I believe I should use `prepareForSegue` or `tableView(..didSelectRowAtIndexPath..)` funcs but I'm not sure how.

Comment: use prepareForSegue while you from VC1 to VC2 and in VC2 use didSelectRowAtIndex while you move from VC2 to VC1

Comment: It's not so simple. Watch answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. You need to use delegates. Look here: http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/